# Test serial correlation for panel data

Tags: time-series, econometrics, panel-data, autocorrelation, economics

I have a set of panel data (including variables X1, X2, X3. and N=193; T=22) these variables are used as independent variables in the model. I want to check the autocorrelation of each of these variables (Ex: Whether variable X has serial correlation during the research period?), what method should I use? Can the using ARMA method?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. You can try Wooldridge 2002 which provides a Woold test for intragroup autocorrelation.The corresponding command in Stata is `xtserial`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).